# Is communication between Node.js app and a remote WebAPI service qualifies as CORS?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm writing an AngularJS SPA, which will need to communicate with a few different WebAPI services.
It is my understanding, that issuing a service request from a Browser, to a service located in a different domain, is considered CORS, and requires special treatment with additional headers set on both sides.
My question is: if my SPA is served by a Node server, and will only make service calls within its own domain, BUT this Node-based service will, in turn, make server-to-server calls to remote WebAPI -  will any part of this considered CORS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, CORS is a specification that is implemented as a security feature in the **browser**.
Your node server does not need any special headers and is free to make http calls to any public resource on the internet.

Here is a browser compatibility table for CORS:

http://enable-cors.org/client.html

Node is not listed on it, because off-course, node is not a browser.